# How do i preserve state and UI changes of only one tab(first) in flutter widget if I have implemented IndexStack widget with many other children tabs?

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, tabview

```
child: Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: [
            PageTemplate(
              pageTitle: "Battery Connection",
              cardListWidget: BatteryConnection(),
            ),
            PageTemplate(
              pageTitle: "Service Status",
              cardListWidget: const StatusCard(),
            ),
            BatteryRegistrationView(mobile: widget.mobileNumber),
            PageTemplate(
              pageTitle: "My Battery Inventory",
              cardListWidget: BatteryCardList(),
            ),
            PageTemplate(
              pageTitle: "Account",
              cardListWidget: const AccountCard(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _getBottomNavigationBar(),
)
```

###### I have implemented above code and I want only first child of IndexStack widget to retain previous UI state after tab navigation, but it preserve state of rest of the children, I just want retain first,

this one,  bottomNavigationBar: _getBottomNavigationBar(), this line I have implemented tab structure,

```
 PageTemplate(
              pageTitle: "Battery Connection",
              cardListWidget: BatteryConnection(),
            ),
```

I tried above method,

- AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
- Stack and OffStage

all works but I have to retain state of only first child or first tab, How can I implement that?